# PHP point to folder

Tags: php, magento-1.7

From a subdirectory I need to trigger a file that is in another directory:

I have a directory: `/httpdocs/douglaslabs/` and I have an `index.php` file in here which should point to:

`/httpdocs/shop/app/mage.php`

What I now got is:

`$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '../shop/app/Mage.php` but it won't work. I'll get the message:

`/httpdocs/douglaslabs../shop/app/Mage.php` was not found

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell from the error messages, your path is incorrect:

```
[..]labs../shop/app
```

One slash is missing there.

So your code shoud read like this:

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../shop/app/Mage.php';
```